# Div set to fixed position not floating with scroll in mobile responsive view

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to add a sticky/fixed bar which should come right after the fixed header for mobile screen width < 420px but even though I have mentioned all the CSS properties which should make the div stick right after the fixed header but its not staying fixed on scroll and I would highly appreciate if anyone can please view this link in mobile view of around 400px using chrome or firebug and let me know what did I do wrong?

Following is the CSS of the div I am trying to float on scroll with the fixed header.

```
#hstickyfor_mobile {
  z-index: 10000;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position is set relative to an ancestor element if it has the `transform` property set ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed)).

In your case, while you properly set `position: fixed`, the `.mobmenu-push-wrap` element has the `transform` property set. So the position of the `hstickyfor_mobile` element is determined relative to the`.mobmenu-push-wrap` element, which is static.

Comment: Thanks a lot Derek, exactly that was the problem.